# How to make an array from child nodes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase for my Swift iOS application. I tried the Firebase tutorials but still no luck for me. I need to make an array from the names of Topics in my `/topics` child.

My Firebase data looks like this:

```
topics
   Topic 1
     Entry 1
        point: 1
        user: user1
     Entry 2
        point: 2
        user: user2
```

I need to make an array consisting of [`Topic 1`, `Topic 2`, ...]. How can I make this array happen? Maybe I'm nesting the data in the incorrect way? Any help would be appreciated.

I also tried to retrieve the data but `snapshot` is a type of `<< error type >>` so I cannot get any value out of it? What might be the problem?

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("topics")

    ref.observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)

    }
```

Comment: I think you might have to restructure your data tree. However, you can retrieve all the topics (which will pull down their children nodes too), then in your app, just access only the Topics then add to array or something like that

Comment: @Rexford do you have any idea how should I structure my data? I guess you get the idea of the app, there are topics and people writing entries to them. Every entry has 2 property suggested in my example.

Comment: Do you need an array containing the topics as string or as mapped objects?

Comment: I need an array of Strings, then I will count the array to find out how many topics there are. @M_G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the keys of the snapshot value into an array:

```
refHandle = postRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let topicsDict = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
  topicsArray = Array(topicsDict.keys)
})
```

Comment: The point I don't understand is what exactly the refHandle is, do I need to create a variable as refHandle before?

Comment: This will be used to unregister the observer when it should not trigger the block anymore. See the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference.html#a92d618b443c649ba9f8c9d938a478c99

Returns
A handle used to unregister this block later using `removeObserverWithHandle:`

Comment: it gives an error if I write down the exactly same thing as you do: "use of unresolved identifier" on refHandle. What should I do?

Comment: Of course you have to introduce it as `let` or `var` depending on how you want to use it. You can leave the assignment out completely if you do not want to unregister later on.

Comment: Okay thanks, but now it gives the error in the .observe section : "Value of type 'FIRDatabaseReferance' has no member 'observe' "

Comment: The code was written like this in the current firebase docs so you maybe have to tweak it to match your Firebase SDK version as well as Swift version.
Reading the dictionary key can also be added to your code snippet as you get the snapshot already as parameter.

Comment: Thanks very much for showing how to make array out of topics, but still have problem with how to retrieve datas. I cannot get the snapshot because there is no more .observe method i guess. There is .observeEventType but when I use it, it again gives error.

Comment: @AtakanCavuslu Three things 1) you do not need refHandle. If you want to get the data from a node once, use ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in.  2) This is the correct answer to your initial question so please accept it. 3) If you have a separate question, as in how to access child data ('datas') within the node, it will require a different answer so please post a separate question.